# how to read data from webservice and print in chatbot using java code

Tags: java, web-services, watson-conversation

> My problem is I want to read data from webservice and print it in
>   chatbot .

Webservice will have **incident number and its status in it** , I have to copy the data from the webservice and print. I try with the code below but I am not sure how to print this data in conversation chat bot.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws IOException {
    String requestMessage = request.getParameter("message");
    String contextString = request.getParameter("context");
    JSONObject contextObject = new JSONObject();
    if(contextString != null) {enter code here
        contextObject = JSONObject.parseObject(contextString);
    }
    System.out.println("Context: ");
    System.out.println(contextObject);
    Map<String, Object> contextMap = Utility.toMap(contextObject);
    if(requestMessage == null || requestMessage.isEmpty()){
        requestMessage = "Greetings";
    }
    if(requestMessage == "1" || requestMessage == "merge id"){
       // throw new NullPointerException();
        requestMessage = "call";
try {
        URL e = new URL(
                "webservice url");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) e.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "TEXT/PLAIN");
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + 
conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");

        String output;
```

Comment: You can pass the data into the conversation as context variable. Context variables can then be used in the dialog node, e.g., to be printed in a response.

Comment: thanks for your response, please  help me with example , i am new to watson and java .

Comment: I assume you already read this: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/dialog-context.html

Comment: hi, thanks for the information,  i have read the link and below is my understanding, please correct me if i am wrong,I will create 
$ticket_details : context variable in my code and write above code in If condition .. then I will add this context variable in my dialog node to print the webservice data..

Comment: the variable needs to be part of "context"

Comment: hi, I have added $ticket_details variable in "context " and add above code but its not working , when i check the details in chatbot its not printing the data from webservice.

Comment: we got the values in the java code  but we are not able to fetch  the data through JSON file.  we have declared the ticket details in context variable, below is the syntax , but we are not able to get those values , could you please let us know how can we proceed with? please provide us the right syntax which will be helpful for us. {
  "context": {
    "ticket_details": "incidentNum"
  },

Answer (score 0):

In the application code you have to create / maintain a variable named JSON `context`. As part of that structure you can defined your own variables with values. The context is passed to Watson Conversation with the [message API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#messages) (either directly or via [Watson SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/)).

Within the workspace editor of Watson Conversation you can now access those context variables. This can be as part of conditions for a dialog node, within a response text, or when assigning new values to context variables. For your case it could be a simple `$ticket_details`. See this [expression reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/reference.html) for details.

Moreover, I wrote a [blog entry that explains even more about variables](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/06/building-chatbots-tips-tricks/) and links to a [GitHub repository with some extended examples](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/watson-conversation-variables).